How can we prove the monotonicity of a function which involves modified Bessel function of the second kind?
I find in Matlab that the function
$$
f(x)=\frac{c}{x}+\frac{K^\prime_\lambda(\sqrt{x})}{K_\lambda(\sqrt{x})}
$$
for $c>0$, when $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}=+\infty$, this function is strictly decreasing at first and then strictly increasing. However, I cannot prove it. Can I get some intuition to prove the monotonicity of the modified Bessel function of the second kind?
